# how best to sandbox firefox and restrict it to one banking site with iptables

Tags: sandbox, iptables, http-referer, onlinebanking

I am trying to set up several "idiot-proof" browser sandboxes that will each allow one user to log into one bank site but do nothing else.  This is for home usage.  The intention is that the user can't accidentally browse to other sites in that firefox session, that anything downloaded stays safe (encrypted), and that issues with firefox itself won't break this security setup.

I've decided to try firejail around firefox with --private-cache --private=secure-homedir (which is encrypted), and used the uMatrix firefox extension with added rules:

```
 * * doc inherit (blocks all direct 1st party sites)

  mybank.com * * allow
```

This works very well.  However, at one point, I accidentally corrupted part of the firefox profile, and the result was that firefox still worked even though uMatrix was broken - allowing the firefox session to browse anywhere.  Not a confidence building event.

So, I would instead like to use firejail's --netfilter=iptablesfile,args... to do what was done by uMatrix, only in a more failsafe way.  I initially configured the iptables file to allow only outbound HTTPS traffic and only for mybank.com, allow DNS and related,established other traffic.  This fails probably because mybank.com's site does "referer" things with 3rd party sites (some of which apparently aren't even HTTPS), without which its own web site isn't very usable.  How do I setup an iptables file that will allow this "referer" traffic only originating from mybank.com?

I have also tried using chromium with its hidden --host-rules option:

```
chromium --host-rules="MAP * ~NOTFOUND, EXCLUDE mybank.com, EXCLUDE *.mybank.com"
```

Again, this works quite well.  But, chromium doesn't firejail as nicely as firefox.  Most importantly, the --host-rules option isn't documented and (like other undocumented switches) might go away, and chromium runs just fine when given a command line option it doesn't understand(!).  That's even less failsafe than my original firefox/uMatrix setup.

I'm open to more failsafe alternatives anyone can suggest...

Comment: It might be the case that https traffic can't really be selectively examined once outside the browser, since the content is opaque to a firewall (or proxy).  Perhaps what I really need is a way to make sure uMatrix is properly running (without trusting the user to always remember to check).  Or, maybe a specific firefox extension just for this purpose, one that would fail safely somehow, and do blocking with whitelisting of one site it is given.

Comment: My latest make-uMatrix-pretty-failsafe idea: start firefox with 2 url args: "firefox did-umatrix-prevent-this.test mybank.com".  If the 1st page isn't uMatrix's blocked page, try again (in case uMatrix loads late) - and if it doesn't become uMatrix's blocked page, quit.  There's got to be a better way...